# Questions about "response.redirect" on Kitura

Tags: javascript, jquery, swift, web

Hi guys, 
I'm not familiar with web server, client and AJAX. I encountered redirect problems on Kitura.
The delete route can redirect to "/api/v1/users/list" succeeded.(I saw a message through print function)
but the browser doesn't reload data(refresh) for /api/v1/users/list.
Please following code, Thanks!

Q1-0)Do I need to perform a manual refresh for browser?
Q1-1)If I should, which side is better for that? (server side or browser side)
Q2)Do I need to do refresh action by manual, when I using AJAX delete method?

```
Server side method "delete"
---------------------------
...
router.delete("/api/v1/users/delete/:id" ....
_ = try? response.redirect("/api/v1/users/list", status: .seeOther)
...

Server side method "get"
------------------------
...
//list all users.
//each user have a delete button that performs AJAX delete method to "/api/v1/users/delete/:id".
router.get("/api/v1/users/list", ... 
print("get /api/v1/users/list")
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answers:

**Q1-0**: In your case, yes.

**Q1-1**: In your case, browser.

**Q2**: In your case, yes.

Longer answer:

This really depends on the architecture of your app:

1. **Client/server:** You build an API that sends/receives JSON or XML through REST endpoints. On top of that, you build a JavaScript client that uses AJAX to communicate with this API. This is what you seem to be doing. However, your AJAX requests should only send/receive JSON or XML data. Any page updating, reloading or redirecting should happen client-side.
2. **Server-side**: Here, most of the logic happens on the server. You use HTTP GET and POST to request pages and submit forms. The server then processes these requests and returns an HTML page for the browser to render. See https://github.com/svanimpe/swift-blog for an example that uses Kitura and Stencil.

Client/server is more flexible as you can build several clients (web as well as native apps) for the same API, but is also more complex, as it's a distributed architecture and usually involves multiple programming languages and some code duplication.
Server-side apps are generally easier to build for beginners as they are monolithic and involve very little non-Swift code (in your case).